# JsStore bulkInsert issue

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have been looking at JsStore and playing with the getting started tutorial for a couple hours now.  I am using the "tutors" database from off the site, and wanted to insert some data.

```
var Value = [{TeacherName: "MR. BAUER", Description: "Lane's Teacher"}, {TeacherName: "MRS. BAUMAN", Description: "Lane's Aide"}, {TeacherName: "MRS. STEWART", Description: "Annabelle's Teacher"}, {TeacherName: "MR. GARLAND", Description: "Alex's Teacher"}];

Connection.insert({
Into: "Teachers",
Values: Value ,//you can insert multiple values at a time
OnSuccess:function (rowsAffected){
if (rowsAffected > 0)
{
alert('Successfully Added');
}
},
OnError:function (error) {
alert(error.value);
}
});
```

This worked great. So next I moved on to the 'bulkInsert' which looked as simple on the documentation as changing 'insert' to 'bulkInsert'

I cleared the cache and ran the page again, and got this error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating
>   the object store's key path did not yield a value.

This is the only change, and I can not see the issue I am missing. Is there an extra step to the bulkInsert that is not listed in the documentation?

Video Sample of the issue: https://youtu.be/d-Jxx54c3dw

Answer (score 1):

In your video, looks like the key path is TeacherId, but in your Values array none of the objects have that property. Maybe that is the issue. Either that or you have autoIncrment disabled by mistake. See [the Structuring the Database section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in docs of jsstore (http://jsstore.net/tutorial/bulk-insert) -

> It is much faster compared to insert api as it does not check and
>   return any thing

It means that all the columns options like auto increment, default etc. wont work. Also it does not make sure that all data has been inserted or not.

The error you are getting says - that you have not supplied any value for primary key. It is because you have specified AutoIncrement for primary key but AutoIncrement wont be calculated when you are using bulkInsert.

Now your question will be then why to use bulk Insert ?

The use of bulk insert is - inserting huge amount of data at a time.

e.g - You have thousands of data in the server or in a excel sheet or a json file and you want to insert these data to indexeddb very fastly without checking or modifying any thing to data.

Hope this is enough explanation for your issue.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is perfect.  I did miss that it would not auto-increment and I needed to supply that field.  That is perfect.